# Getting the route name inside a service in symfony

Tags: symfony

guys so I have a service in which i have a constructor that accepts router service.

My question is how can I know the current route name?

This is my service:

```
class Navigation
{
    protected $modules;

    protected $router;

    public function __construct($modules, $router)
    {
        $this->modules = $modules;
        $this->router = $router;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to inject "@request_stack" after that

```
$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if your class is an AbstractController you can directly use this without further dependency injection:

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->get('_route')
```